# Remove parenthesis from SQLAlchemy select_from

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've got a PostgreSQL function that `RETURNS TABLE`, so it's valid to use it in a query like so:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM my_func(arg1 => :arg_1, arg2 => :arg_2)
```

I'm trying to create that with SQLAlchemy.

I've created the `text()` query object like so:

```
my_func = text("my_func(arg1 => :arg_1, arg2 => :arg_2)")
```

Set up bind params:

```
my_func = my_func.bindparams(bindparam("arg_1", value=arg_1), ...)
```

And because my function returns a table I've declared the columns on it too:

```
my_func = my_func.columns(col1=INTEGER, col2=TEXT)
```

Elsewhere in my code I am using this object to create the actual query:

```
select_query = select(my_func.c.col1).select_from(my_func).all()
```

I got this pattern from the tutorial on the `text()` object. But, when I go to render that final `select()` query, SQLAlchemy is coming up with SQL like this:

```
SELECT col1 FROM (my_func(arg1 => :arg_1, arg2 => :arg_2))
```

Which is a syntax error in PostgreSQL because of the extra parens around the FROM part of the clause, as if it were a complete subquery on its own.

As a workaround I changed the initial `text()` to do `SELECT * FROM my_func(...)` to make it into a proper subquery. That gets me working SQL but I wonder if I can get SQLAlchemy to treat the function as if it were a literal table name.